# How to host an android application without using localhost

Tags: android, sql, localhost

I've developed an android application that uses a SQL database which is running successfully on localhost. Now I want to give a demo of my application that a user could run remotely.  I need to send the apk to another person.  I can access the app because I am on the localhost, but how can the remote person access it?

Comment: You can use a service called Firebase: [(https://firebase.google.com) for that

Comment: It is unclear if you used an emulator or an Android device.

Comment: I've used an android device

Answer (score 0):

For android app your app hosting best solution is **Andorid Firebase** and this service is **Free**.

[Firebase Hosting Referance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/)

It's also work like a web app so another person can view the demo as you required.

Firebase also provide *Storage*, *Database* and so on feature that you should be like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to tell the other person to use the internet address of your router.

Then on your router forward the used port to the ip address of the pc where your service runs.

Please dont talk about localhost the way you do. Every device is its own localhost. So also your Android device is a localhost. And every pc is.